# Pytorch :RuntimeError: Cannot initialize CUDA without ATen_cuda library

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am new to model training in python I have installed pytorch using :

pip install torch==1.4.0+cpu torchvision==0.5.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Now my model is giving me this error :
RuntimeError: Cannot initialize CUDA without ATen_cuda library. PyTorch splits its backend into two shared libraries: a CPU library and a CUDA library; this error has occurred because you are trying to use some CUDA functionality, but the CUDA library has not been loaded by the dynamic linker for some reason.  The CUDA library MUST be loaded, EVEN IF you don't directly use any symbols from the CUDA library! One common culprit is a lack of -Wl,--no-as-needed in your link arguments; many dynamic linkers will delete dynamic library dependencies if you don't depend on any of their symbols.  You can check if this has occurred by using ldd on your binary to see if there is a dependency on *_cuda.so library.

I know its cuda problem but I have defined in my model if cuda is not available then cpu.My code is

```
# import the usual resources
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# import utilities to keep workspaces alive during model training
#from workspace_utils import active_session

# watch for any changes in model.py, if it changes, re-load it automatically
#%load_ext autoreload
#%autoreload 2

## TODO: Define the Net in models.py

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import datetime

## TODO: Once you've define the network, you can instantiate it
# one example conv layer has been provided for you
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch
from torchvision import transforms, utils
from models import Net
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda:0")
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print(device)
print(torch.version)
net = Net().to(device)
print(net)

from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms, utils

# the dataset we created in Notebook 1 is copied in the helper file `data_load.py`
from data_load import FacialKeypointsDataset
# the transforms we defined in Notebook 1 are in the helper file `data_load.py`
from data_load import Rescale, RandomCrop, Normalize, ToTensor

## TODO: define the data_transform using transforms.Compose([all tx's, . , .])
# order matters! i.e. rescaling should come before a smaller crop

# testing that you've defined a transform

data_transform = transforms.Compose(
    [Rescale(250), RandomCrop(224),
     Normalize(), ToTensor()])
assert (data_transform is not None), 'Define a data_transform'

# create the transformed dataset
transformed_dataset = FacialKeypointsDataset(
    csv_file=
    "person_keypoints_train2017_foot_v1\\NEWOUT.csv",
    root_dir=
    "person_keypoints_train2017_foot_v1\\out\\",
    transform=data_transform)

print('Number of images: ', len(transformed_dataset))

# iterate through the transformed dataset and print some stats about the first few samples
for i in range(4):
    sample = transformed_dataset[i]
    print(i, sample['image'].size(), sample['keypoints'].size())

# load training data in batches
batch_size = 32

train_loader = DataLoader(
    transformed_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

# load in the test data, using the dataset class
# AND apply the data_transform you defined above

# create the test dataset
test_dataset = FacialKeypointsDataset(
    csv_file=
    "person_keypoints_val2017_foot_v1\\NEWOUT.csv",
    root_dir=
    "person_keypoints_val2017_foot_v1\\ready_val_out\\",
    transform=data_transform)

test_loader = DataLoader(
    test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

# test the model on a batch of test images


def net_sample_output():

    # iterate through the test dataset
    for i, sample in enumerate(test_loader):

        # get sample data: images and ground truth keypoints
        images = sample['image']
        key_pts = sample['keypoints']

        # convert images to FloatTensors
        images = images.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)

        # forward pass to get net output
        output_pts = net(images)

        # reshape to batch_size x 68 x 2 pts ##CHANGED
        output_pts = output_pts.view(output_pts.size()[0], 6, -1)

        # break after first image is tested
        if i == 0:
            return images, output_pts, key_pts


test_images, test_outputs, gt_pts = net_sample_output()

# print out the dimensions of the data to see if they make sense
print(test_images.data.size())
print(test_outputs.data.size())
print(gt_pts.size())


def show_all_keypoints(image, predicted_key_pts, gt_pts=None):
    """Show image with predicted keypoints"""
    # image is grayscale
    plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
    plt.scatter(
        predicted_key_pts[:, 0],
        predicted_key_pts[:, 1],
        s=20,
        marker='.',
        c='m')
    # plot ground truth points as green pts
    if gt_pts is not None:
        plt.scatter(gt_pts[:, 0], gt_pts[:, 1], s=20, marker='.', c='g')


# visualize the output
# by default this shows a batch of 10 images
def visualize_output(test_images, test_outputs, gt_pts=None, batch_size=4):
    fig = plt.figure()
    iimg = 1
    sp = 1
    for i in range(batch_size):

        iimg += 1
        if i % 2 == 0:
            sp += 1
            iimg = 1
        fig.add_subplot(sp, batch_size, iimg)

        # un-transform the image data
        image = test_images.cpu(
        )[i].data  # get the image from it's Variable wrapper
        image = image.numpy()  # convert to numpy array from a Tensor
        image = np.transpose(
            image, (1, 2, 0))  # transpose to go from torch to numpy image

        # un-transform the predicted key_pts data
        predicted_key_pts = test_outputs.cpu()[i].data
        predicted_key_pts = predicted_key_pts.numpy()
        # undo normalization of keypoints
        predicted_key_pts = predicted_key_pts * 50.0 + 100

        # plot ground truth points for comparison, if they exist
        ground_truth_pts = None
        if gt_pts is not None:
            ground_truth_pts = gt_pts[i]
            ground_truth_pts = ground_truth_pts * 50.0 + 100

        # call show_all_keypoints
        show_all_keypoints(
            np.squeeze(image), predicted_key_pts, ground_truth_pts)

        plt.axis('off')

    plt.show()


# call it
#visualize_output(test_images, test_outputs, gt_pts)

## TODO: Define the loss and optimization
import torch.optim as optim

#criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

#optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
optimizer = optim.Adam(params=net.parameters(), lr=0.001)


def train_net(n_epochs):
    print("Training...")

    # prepare the net for training
    net.train()

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

        running_loss = 0.0

        # train on batches of data, assumes you already have train_loader
        for batch_i, data in enumerate(train_loader):
            # get the input images and their corresponding labels
            images = data['image']
            key_pts = data['keypoints']

            # flatten pts
            key_pts = key_pts.view(key_pts.size(0), -1)

            # convert variables to floats for regression loss
            key_pts = key_pts.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
            images = images.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)

            # forward pass to get outputs
            output_pts = net(images)
            #output_pts = output_pts.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
            #print(output_pts.type)
            #print(key_pts.type)
            # calculate the loss between predicted and target keypoints
            loss = criterion(output_pts, key_pts)

            # zero the parameter (weight) gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # backward pass to calculate the weight gradients
            loss.backward()

            # update the weights
            optimizer.step()

            # print loss statistics
            running_loss += loss.item()
            if batch_i % 32 == 31:  # print every 10 batches
                print(datetime.datetime.now())
                print('Epoch: {}, Batch: {}, Avg. Loss: {}'.format(
                    epoch + 1, batch_i + 1, running_loss / 1000))
                running_loss = 0.0

    print('Finished Training')


# train your network
n_epochs = 500  # start small, and increase when you've decided on your model structure and hyperparams

# this is a Workspaces-specific context manager to keep the connection
# alive while training your model, not part of pytorch
#with active_session():

#train_net(n_epochs)

## TODO: change the name to something uniqe for each new model
model_dir = 'D:\\Users\\Tsvetan\\FootDataset\\'
model_name = 'keypoints.pt'

cpnt = torch.load(model_dir + "500" + model_name)
print()
print()
for key in cpnt.keys():
    print(key + " {}".format(cpnt[key]))
print()
print()
net.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_dir + "500" + model_name))

train_net(10)

net.eval()

# after training, save your model parameters in the dir 'saved_models'
#torch.save(net.state_dict(), model_dir + model_name)

# Get the weights in the first conv layer, "conv1"
# if necessary, change this to reflect the name of your first conv layer
weights1 = net.conv1.weight.data.cpu()

w = weights1.numpy()

filter_index = 0

print(w[filter_index][0])
print(w[filter_index][0].shape)

# display the filter weights
#plt.imshow(w[filter_index][0], cmap='gray')

####
test_images, test_outputs, gt_pts = net_sample_output()
visualize_output(test_images, test_outputs, gt_pts)
```

I have re-write the condition but its still giving me error.

Comment: I just solved it!! I rewirte this torch.cuda.FloatTensor into torch.FloatTensor

Comment: How did you solve it @hamza?

Comment: Thanks a lot Hamza Ahmed Jamee!